# Subgroups of $GL_n(K)$ preserving polynomials

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, linear-transformations

Vinberg in his algebra book, when introducing groups, mentions the following (translated from Russian):

> [...] Analogously, nonsingular linear transformations of the space $K^n$ [where K is some field] that preserve a given polynomial in $n$ variables constitute a subgroup of the group $GL_n(K)$. Nonsingular linear transformations of the space $\Bbb R^n$ that preserve the polynomial $x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots +x_n^2$ are called *orthogonal transformations*; they form a subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ called *the orthogonal group* and are denoted $O_n$.

Now I realise that $O_n$ is a group and I know that it is the group of isometries fixing the origin, but that is because I know a priori about it and that the polynomial in question is actually the Euclidean distance and therefore any transformation preserving it would be an isometry. For a general polynomial $p$ in $K[x_1,\dots, x_n]$, how is one supposed to tell what the subgroup preserving $p$ would look like, for example for $p=x_1+\dots+x_n$? Or, if symmetry of the polynomial simplifies the group somehow, for an even more general, non-symmetric one like, say, $p=\sum x_i^i$? In fact, I am still not quite sure whether it even is a subgroup (I can see how the identity and composition might belong to it, but does the inverse) or what is meant by "preserving the polynomial". Is the implication that a transformation $T$ preserves a polynomial $p$ if and only if $p(T[x_1,\dots,x_n])=p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$? And finally, does there exist a polynomial for each subgroup $H$ of $GL_n(K)$, that $H$ preserves, or are there subgroups that can't be described this way?

Comment: I think, you managed to ask 4 questions in one post. One of them is essentially unanswerable.

Comment: I count 2... I suppose the unanswerable one is about whether a polynomial exists for each subgroup?

Comment: Questions in this post: "how is one supposed to tell what the subgroup preserving $p$ would look like?" "Does symmetry of the polynomial simplify the group somehow?" "Is it even is a subgroup?" "does there exist a polynomial for each subgroup $H$?"

Comment: At the risk of coming across as impertinent and demanding, I do think that the first 3 are essentially one question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to the quickly answerable questions:

First, a proof that the non-singular $p$-preserving transformations form a subgroup. We have a polynomial $p:K^n \to K$, and $A$ is $p$-preserving if $p(Ax) = p(x)$ for all $x$. For closure under multiplication, it suffices to note that for $A,B$ in the subgroup
$$
p(ABx) = p(A(Bx)) = p(Bx) = p(x).
$$
If $A$ is an element of the group, then we have
$$
p(A^{-1}x) = p(A(A^{-1}x)) = p(x).
$$
I suspect that there exist subgroups of $GL_n(K)$ that cannot be described as the preservers of polynomials.  For instance, the unitary matrices in $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ are the preservers of the function $p(x) = |x_1|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2$, which is not a complex polynomial on $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Proving that there is *no* complex polynomial that works is a bit trickier; I suspect that we can do this, however, using the fact that the unitary matrices form a compact subset of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$.

Arguably, this is a bit of a cop-out since the $p$ described above *is* a real polynomial on the complex and real parts.

---

An attempted proof of my conjecture: we note that $A$ is a $p$-preserver iff $p(Ax) - p(x)$ is the zero-polynomial over $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  Consider the element of $(\Bbb C[a_{ij}])[x]$. That is, write each coefficient of a product of some $x_i$ as a polynomial of the entries of $A$. Setting each of these of these polynomials equal to zero gives us a system of equations
$
p_1(A) = 0 , \dots , p_m(A) = 0
$
for which $A$ is a $p$ preserver iff it is non-singular and solves the system.

In other words, the $p$-preservers (if we include the singular matrices) form a Zariski-closed subset of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$.  However, because of [INSERT ALGEBRAIC GEOMETRY FACT HERE], this implies that the $A$-preservers must be either finite or form an unbounded subset of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$.

It follows that the unitary matrices cannot be a set of polynomial preservers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got stumped by the inverse bit. Would you have anything to say about how the preserver subgroup of a given polynomial would look like? That would really be the meat of what I'm asking and what I'm most interested in.

Comment: @V.Ch. what does "look like" mean in this context? Unless you know what you're looking for, I don't think that there's a good way to broach that one.

Comment: @V.Ch. Here's a characterization you might like, though.  The matrices in this group can be extracted from the polynomial zero-set $p(Ax) - p(x) = 0$.  By looking at the coefficients to the $x$-variables in terms of the entries of $A$, you obtain a system of equations that the entries of $A$ must satisfy.

Comment: I realise that my wording is a bit vague and in all honesty I can't give a simple, satisfying answer, but something along the lines of the example in the original post would be nice (i.e. $O_n$ preserves this polynomial and is hence the group of isometries). I suppose that there might not be any way at all of intepreting the group for a general polynomial and that each case could require some sort of ad hoc explanation, but I didn't know any other way of asking. I guess I'm not quite sure myself what the question is...

Comment: @V.Ch. you might be interested in the [generalized orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group), which preserves a different set of polynomials. Note also that the special linear group is the group of determinant-preserving polynomials.

Comment: @V.Ch. A clarification of my earlier comment, which I try to exploit in the proof that I added.  The set of polynomial preservers (if we include singular matrices) necessarily forms an [affine variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety) in $GL_n(K)$.

Comment: @V.Ch. Some more examples: every [classical Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group#The_classical_groups) except for the special unitary group is a set of polynomial-preservers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer in the fullest and even then some!

Comment: @V.Ch. You're welcome; I'm happy to have answered an interesting question

Comment: There are many examples of subgroups of $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$ which are not Zariski-closed (even over reals), for instance, $GL(n, {\mathbb Z})$, or not even closed in the classical topology: For instance,  $GL(n,{\mathbb Q})$, or some finitely generated subgroups.